Execute GraphQL mutation via Apollo on NuxtJS
I know that to execute a GraphQL query via Apollo on NuxtJS 2, we can do like this :


import articlesQuery from "~/apollo/queries/articles/recent-articles";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      articles: {
        data: [],
      },
  },
  apollo: {
    articles: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: articlesQuery,
    },
  },
};



But to execute a mutation (to create an entry in Strapi Content Manager for exemple), I couldn’t find very much informations.
I was trying this way, but unsuccessfully :


import createPost from "~/apollo/queries/actualitesEtNewsletters/createArticle";

export default {
  apollo: {
    createActualitesEtNewsletters: {
      mutation: createPost,
      context: {
        headers: {
          authorization:
            "Bearer JWT_TOKEN",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};



Feel free to ask for additional informations.
Thank you !

I found the solution ! :


export default {
  methods: {
    createPost() {
      this.$apollo
        .mutate({
          mutation: createPost,
          context: {
            headers: {
              authorization:
                "Bearer JWT_TOKEN",
            },
          },
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Error
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createPost();
  },
};



